# Codeigniter Youtube Data Api by Jim Saunders

Tags: codeigniter, api, youtube

I have my consumer key and consumer secret and youtube api key in my config file like so:

```
$config['youtube_api_key'] = my api key;
$config['google_consumer_key'] = my consumer key;
$config['google_consumer_secret'] = my consumer secret;
```

I have a controller called youtube_api (made from example.php from jim) and I tried calling the public function:

```
public function youtube_no_auth()
    {
        $params['apikey'] = $this->config->item('youtube_api_key');
        $this->load->library('youtube', $params);
        echo $this->youtube->getKeywordVideoFeed('pac man');
    }
```

I am running into the following problems:

1. `$this->config->item` didn't work, i get the following error:

   - Call to a member function item() on a non-object
   - I solved this by using config_item('youtube_api_key');
2. `$this->load->library('youtube', $params)` gave the following error:

   - Call to a member function library() on a non-object

I thought there was an issue with scope so I did this `$CI =& get_instance()` and `$CI->load->library`, but that didn't work either...

Would someone please kindly point me in the right direction? I'm kind of lost with this issue. I have been searching high and low for an answer but couldn't find one...

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that the example constructor needs this line at the top

```
parent::__construct
```

That should fix the issues you were having. So your constructor should look like:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('session');
}
```

There is no need to store CodeIgniter in a private variable. Just use the constructor as outline in the CodeIgniter documentation.

I have updated the GIT repo to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem, you have to configure it as an object, in your _construct as follow :

```
class Example extends CI_Controller
{
  private $CI;
  public function __construct()
{
 parent::__construct();

$this->CI =& get_instance();
$this->CI->load->library('session');

$oauth = array();
$oauth['oauth_token_secret']='';
$oauth['oauth_token']='';

}
```

see here for a very similar subject:

[YouTube API Request : How could I get the Right token ( about Jim S.' code )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399738/youtube-api-request-how-could-i-get-the-right-token-about-jim-s-code/8399975#8399975)

and

[Google Oauth for YouTube : Why do I get "Undefined index: oauth_token" ( Jim S.' code )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428547/google-oauth-for-youtube-why-do-i-get-undefined-index-oauth-token-jim-s/8429071#8429071)

let me know if that solved your pb