# Google Oauth for YouTube : Why do I get "Undefined index: oauth_token" ( Jim S.' code )

Tags: php, codeigniter, oauth, youtube, google-openid

I got a little problem with the OAuth for Google, I use the Jim Saunder Libraire for CodeIgniter (http://codeigniter.com/wiki/OAuth_for_Google) but when I came to my access_youtube function, which look like that :

```
public function access_youtube()
{ //STEP 2

// Here is the first call to load the library 
    $params['key'] = 's390075769.onlinehome.fr';
    $params['secret'] = 'iHD72YKzWmbm8VTwncht_E-d';

// We  can change the signing algorithm and http method by setting the following in your params array.
    $params['algorithm'] = 'HMAC-SHA1';
    // $params['method'] = "GET";

// We need to reload the library since we left our site beetween Step 1 & 2.
    $this->load->library('google_oauth', $params);

// We are using HMAC signing you need to specify the token_secret you got from the request step as the second parameter of this method. So
    $token_secret = $this->session->userdata('token_secret');
    $oauth = $this->google_oauth->get_access_token(false, $token_secret);

// The access method will return an array with keys of ‘oauth_token’, and ‘oauth_token_secret’ 
// These values are your access token and your access token secret. We should store these in our database.  
    $this->session->set_userdata('oauth_token', $oauth['oauth_token']);
    $this->session->set_userdata('oauth_token_secret', $oauth['oauth_token_secret']);

// Now you have an access token and can make google service requests on your users behalf
    redirect(site_url());
}
```

I got several error messages :

> Undefined index: oauth_token
>
> Undefined index: oauth_token_secret

which refer to the lines $this->session->set_userdata ...

and, after each error message I get :

> Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /homepages/7/d390075755/htdocs/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)
>   Filename: libraries/Session.php
>   Line Number: 671

which, I think is linked with the previous error message.

so I tried that in the constructor :

```
class Example extends CI_Controller
{
private $CI;
public function __construct()
{
     parent::__construct();

    $this->CI =& get_instance();
    $this->CI->load->library('session');

    $oauth = array();
    $oauth['oauth_token_secret']='';
    $oauth['oauth_token']='';

}
```

just before my function but it doesn't do anything .. and I'm affraid I'm gonna loose my session variables stock by google ... isn't it ? Do I get my tokens from google ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly i am not sure how Session will be managed by PHP code so will be of little help for you.
It seems that this line is the cause

```
$oauth = $this->google_oauth->get_access_token(false, $token_secret);
```

you are trying to get access_token from the Google to send request to Google API to get user information who ever authorize your application and i guess Google is not returning what has been expected from them.
this can be due to type mismatch in the request data as what Google Oauth is expecting from you and what actually you are sending

In you case i would have used debugger of my Eclipse to see what exactly is going on but for OAuth i already told you in earlier question

1. You  need to store that token you getting at your first step.
2. Once your user is back from authenticate them-self you need to get access_token using that request token
3. Once you have request token you are ready to make final API call and it seems that some how your code is failing to get the data from session

Comment: Thank you Again umesh, Well I found my problem :

Comment: everythin is due to my url: in fact I got all the necessary information, when I retrive my url from google, I got, as written up there something like that :

Comment: BUT in fact this url is not sent back correctly, so when I correct it mannualy, what I do is changing all the %2F by / and =& by ?, last time I forgot changing the one right after the "oauth_token=" so the access function didn't get the oauth token, that's why it didn't workd, so how could I code it in order to have the right url automaticly ? I mean it has to change all the %2F and &= automatically. How could I do that ?

Comment: sorry for parsing the answer, if you click on my link you will see it by yourself, try accessing the http://s390075769.onlinehome.fr/index.php?/example/request_youtube
 and then change the url you got after authorizing the app, check the url and change it manualy and you'll see in the print_f session data (in the header) that the oauth token and oauth token secret are there

Comment: @user1083453: in that case you need to use url encoding something like http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php.i saw your example and that is basically the URL has been encoded like spaces and other things has been concerted.you need to get it back in your PHP code like you can access those parameters from request object by putting there name.

Comment: Okay, thanks Umesh, but I don't really see where to put the urlencode function , in the access_youtube function ? the request? or just before the redirect ?because I have this url from google, and it is redirected to my main webpage ..